# How to query multiple data for a single PR and put it a .csv file in Powershell

Tags: powershell, api, azure-devops

I am trying to query the data of a pull request from Azure Devops and put it in a conditional way to .csv file.

**Step1: I am fetching PRs and associated data with it.

Step2: Querying only commitID,status,comments, Author related to a particular PR.

Step3: Need a data of all those commits IDs and comments for a single PR and like that for all the listed PRs from the step 1.**

```
$organization = "{organization name}" // organization name
$project = "{project name}"  // project name
$repo = "{repo name}" // repo name
$pat = "<PAT>"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "", $pat)))
$baseUrl = 'https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/pullrequests?api-version=5.1' 
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}  -Method GET -ContentType 'application/json'
$response.value | Select-Object -Property pullRequestId, @{n='Author';e={$_.authoredBy.displayName}}, @{n='CommitID';e={$_.lastMergeSourceCommit.commitId}}, status, creationDate | ConvertTo-csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "`t" | Out-File C:\Temp\PRData.csv
```

From this I can able to query the data but I am getting only **single reponses like "lastSourceCommitID" will be listed for a PR, but I need the data like for a single PR need to list all the associated commitIDs/comments like that**

Comment: This is not a git question. This is about an API of a provider.

Answer (score 2):

[Get Pull Requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/get-pull-requests?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) does not support the retrieving of commits and work items. For each pull request:

1. Use [Get Pull Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/get-pull-request?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0) with `includeCommits=true&includeWorkItemRefs=true` parameters
2. And [Pull Request Threads - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-threads/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) and [Pull Request Thread Comments - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-thread-comments/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0)

Comment: Thank you for this, it will work for a single pull request manually. But I want the data of commit id, comments of all the PRs which are listed. Once if I execute the script it should automatically pull all the PRs ID and related associated data with it.

Comment: Any update to this will be very helpfull :)